# How can I specify an Azure tenant name?

Tags: azure, entra-id

How can I specify an Azure tenant name? I mean {something}.onmicrosoft.com name.

I have tried to register a new Azure tenant a few times and each time I created a new Microsoft account and then a new tenant and it never asks for tenant name and instead creates tenant name based on account email. Something like {firstnamelastnamegmail}.onmicrosoft.com

However, I have seen primary tenants with nice names like {a-word}.onmicrosoft.com, obviously not generated from emails. Have no idea who configured them so can't ask directly.

So, How can I specify an Azure tenant name?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty good question; you can create new Azure AD tenants in the Azure portal, but this requires already having a valid user account from an existing tenant to log in to said portal.

The only way I found to create a new Azure AD tenant *from scratch* and be able to choose its name is to sign up for a Office 365 / Microsoft 365 trial subscription (business or enterprise); this will create a new Azure AD tenant and will ask you for its name.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Azure AD tenant from inside the Azure portal, the wizard asks you to provide a tenant name.

[image]

Comment: This requires logging in to the Azure portal with an existing account, though.